# iPhone Attributed String

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

Any ideas on how to get the functionality of an attributed string on an iPhone.

Specifically, I am writing out chemical compounds and want to properly display subscripts:  for example:

H<sub>2</sub>O   (the 2 should be a subscript)

Thanks for any suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a UIWebView and HTML, or draw it yourself using the NSString + UIKit additions, or CoreGraphics.

Answer (score 6):

You may find it more convenient to use the Unicode characters set up for subscripts:

SUBSCRIPT TWO is U+2082: H₂0

Answer (score 0):

Just posting this to help others trying to make the scientific notation work. Works for 3.2 and higher (maybe lower, just give it a shot ;))

```
// Property to show
NSString *formula = cellData.formula;

// Setup font
UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Dax-Bold" size:5];

// Draw property
UIGraphicsPushContext(context);
[formula drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(cellData.rect.origin.x + 2, cellData.rect.origin.y + 15) withFont:font];
UIGraphicsPopContext();
```

The `drawAtPoint:` uses the current context so make sure you use this method in you drawRect: method.

I had to wrap the `drawAtPoint:` method with two UIGraphics methods to make sure my text got rendered in a multi thread application.

Make sure that your font supports the unicode characters. If it doesn't the default font will be used. You can add missing font glyphs with a tool called FontLab.